# Connecting yeoman (+angular) with database

Tags: database, angularjs, sqlite, yeoman

I am rewriting my JavaScript app using Yeoman and AngularJS. So far, I used simple webpy framework and everything was fine - I used ajax calls to get data from server, server was connected to sqlite database and everything worked.

Now, I'm deeply confused and have no idea how to connect webapp scaffolded by yeoman and angular with my sqlite db. I know that yeoman is built on node.js but I'm not sure what should I do to get working server side.

I know that this question is more about architecture but I was not able find on the internet how to connect this two technologies: yeoman (with angular) and sqlite database.

What should I use?

Answer (score 0):

Angular is a front-end framework.  You must have a back-end server to communicate to your database.  You talk to it with Angular via a RESTful service using $resource or $http or some 3rd party library like RestAngular.